# Is StatelessSession faster than Session?

Tags: java, hibernate

As we know `StatelessSession` directly deals with database rows unlike Session.
and my question is,can we use `StatelessSession` for small number of inserts,updates for improving 
performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It strongly depends how you use it. Caching in general is invented to increase performance, but the problem with "normal" hibernate session is that it gives you no option to switch caching off. I've written a lot of times database access using Spring JDBC to prevent session overhead, and performance was increased greatly.

So good written application should increase performance greatly using StatelessSession. Bad written application will probably slow down, because forces caching in Hibernate was thought as remedy to users not controlling when and how many times their code will read something from DB...

Answer (score 2):

`StatelessSession` isn't simply a session with caching turned off; it's a completely different kind of session, where many operation aren't even supported. So if you have a piece of code that doesn't break its constraints, it won't hurt to use the stateless session and it may help to make it faster.

I use stateless sessions a lot because I avoid using Hibernate for persistent state management and instead keep to the simple and direct HQL queries. When saving new records, however, a regular session is unavoidable: Hibernate doesn't support `insert` statements with literal data.